# Way to make mixed text and math mode bold with a single command

Tags: math-mode, formatting, bold, boldmath

Is there a way to make the following bold by wrapping in a single command?

```
This is a some text with $\psi$ and other math symbols such as $\Delta m$ etc.
```

Or at least a single command to work on `$\psi$` only (that is including the dollars), I do not want to do things like:

```
\bfseries{text and here} $\mathbf{\Delta m}$.
```

Comment: `\bfseries{text and here}` is wrong (probably) you want `{\bfseries text and here}` or `\textbf{text and here}` but use `\bfseries\boldmath` to make text and math bold

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`\bfseries\boldmath` (note that neither of these takes an argument).

```
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength\textwidth{2cm}
\begin{document}

This is a some text with $\psi$ and other math symbols such as $\Delta m$ etc.

{\bfseries\boldmath
This is a some text with $\psi$ and other math symbols such as $\Delta m$ etc.
}

\end{document}
```